# How to match this wall texture

Tags: drywall, patching-drywall, texture

I'm having trouble matching this drywall texture:

[image]

[image]

Would appreciate help on this.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you having trouble with?

Comment: @mmathis I don't know what is this texture and how to match it. Doesn't look like knockdown to me 

Comment: Kinda looks like popcorn, that's been scraped off and painted over, with a dirty brush. Definitely "spattered" on, with a gun though...

Comment: Pretty sure it is a "skip trowel".  I think sometimes they even add sand or something to it to make it grainy.

Comment: @Damon how do you mix/apply it?

Comment: I do not know enough to give you details.  I feel comfortable doing almost anything BESIDES hand textures.

Answer (score 2):

That's known as a "knockdown" texture, as it's sprayed on the wall and later "knocked down" with a wide taping knife.

Exactly how it's done is beyond the scope of this answer, but here are some resources.

- http://www.familyhandyman.com/drywall/ceiling-texture/how-to-apply-knock-down-texture/view-all
- http://homeguides.sfgate.com/install-knockdown-texture-drywall-surface-21287.html

Comment: Hmm I thought knockdown results in smaller and more edgy spots. The ones I have are much larger

Comment: It depends largely on the mud mix and technique.

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment? Wall texture varies widely depending on a number of factors, but you don't get uniform plateaus like this without a trowelling technique commonly known as knockdown. If you disagree, at least offer a reason.

Comment: Down vote was because It is not a knock down.

Comment: Left a comment on the OP question.

Answer (score 0):

That is skip trowel texture. Easily confused for knock down in a lot of cases. Because im not the best at verbal, or written explanation, i found a video that should help you out immensely. Here you go, and best of luck. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=864zytTOoq4

Comment: StackExchange policy expects you to include at least some highlights of the technique shown in the video. After all, videos disappear all the time. It doesn't have to be fancy or well written, just something that will last longer than a random video.