# What is this wall covering type?

Tags: walls

Can anyone identify what this wall is made of? It looks like some kind of plaster to me, but I'm not sure. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to match this wall texture](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/102610/how-to-match-this-wall-texture) or [How do I achieve this texture?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/133235/how-do-i-achieve-this-texture).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a spray on texture that was knocked down. Basically this is Sheetrock mud that was thinned down and put in a special gun to “spray splatter” the mud on the wall, when I do this I use lower air flow and larger nozzles to provide a larger “splatter” then go back with a wide 12-18” mud knife and knock it down that’s why it looks flat, in stead of an orange peal that is smaller spatter at higher airflow and left to dry, these are very common surface finishes, both are difficult to match but not impossible.

Comment: Just to add. They sell this sort of texture by the can, it's called knock-down texture. If you need to do a patch; grab a can of that and a special knock down knife (it's better for this than a regular putty knife) and follow the instruction on the can. I would suggest a practice run if possible.